# CSS transform set via JS conflicting with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transform, css-animations

I'm rather used to using animations etc. but this one has got me stumped. I have a CSS animation like so on a inline-block div element.

```
0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
  transform: translateY(40px);
}

100% {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

fired with

```
animation: fade-in-b 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) forwards;
```

I then wish to add a parallax effect to the element when scrolling, so JS modifies the transform property also using translateY(). The problem is that this is not taken into account.

[Chrome's debug showing both transforms being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMA21.png)

I would rather not remove the `forwards` fill-mode as this is just a simple example of an animation and some other more complex animations depend on it. I have also tried with `translate3d` but with the same results.

It appears that the CSS animation has priority over the JS applied CSS, is this the intended behaviour? I guess I could remove the CSS animation via javascript before applying the transform, but if there's anything easier I'm all ears. I can't seem to find anything online to help me out so any hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I wish there was a more complete code that i could test, have you tried to use a wrapper so that the 2 `transform` are applied to different elements?

Comment: Hi, yes applying it to a wrapper works but it kinda defeats the purpose. Here's a [quick fiddle with the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/saminton/wpuaafv0/4). The red and blue block should both have the parallax effect. when inspecting you can see the transform being applied to both.

I'll try and extract the JS from the framework and put it in the fiddle so you can see what's going on.